# Achieve fly/fade in text on scroll

Tags: jquery, text, scroll

I'm looking to achieve the text effect used on this page under the "Crafted for creativity" section, where the text slides and fades in on scroll, how would I do this?
See this page: http://www.fiftythree.com/pencil

Also looking to make this work on mobile.

Thanks!

Comment: Can't see the animation in my browser :S

Comment: Theirs doesn't work on mobile if you're using mobile...

Comment: Ah it's a parallax scrolling. It's a technique where background images move slower than that of the containing element. You can check this simple tutorial to get things started. [A Simple Parallax Scrolling Technique](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/simple-parallax-scrolling-technique/)

Comment: No I'm talking about the text itself. Not the images.

Comment: I see. I have posted an answer below, check if that might help you.

Answer (score 2):

On `scroll()` get the window `scrollTop()` value then compare with the each elements `top` `position()`. If the `scrollTop()` is greater than a certain elements `top position` apply the animation/fading.

If you have a markup like this.

```
<div>
    <section>First</section>
    <section>Second</section>
    <section>Third</section>
    <section>Fourth</section>
    <section>Fifth</section>
</div>
```

This is the solution:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
var st = $(this).scrollTop(),
    winH = $(this).height(),
    /* you can set this add, 
    depends on where you want the animation to start
    for example if the section height is 100 and you set add of 50,
    that means if 50% of the section is revealed 
    on the bottom of viewport animate text
    */
    add = 150;

$('section').each(function(){
    var pos = $(this).position().top;

    if(st + winH >= pos + add){
        $(this).stop().animate({opacity:1, marginTop:10},'fast');
    }else{
        $(this).stop().animate({opacity:0, marginTop:0},'fast');
    }
});
});
```

See this **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mark_s/29m3U/3/)**